# Custom view for authenticated user in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3, laravel-authorization

I'm developing a simple login in `laravel 5.3`.

I'm having two `dashboard` in which one is meant for `admins` and other one for `subscribers`. I've gone through the documentation of Authentication there is path customization where if I can change the `$redirectTo = '/home'` to any of the routes it will redirect views respectively.

I've a column in my user table named is_admin which is holding a boolean value.

I'm trying to place following codes in the `LoginController` according to the documentation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use  \Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
//     protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */

    public function redirectPath()
    {      
        if (Auth::user()->is_admin == 0)
        {     

            return redirect()->intended('/memberprofile');   
        }
        else 
        {

          return redirect('/dashboard');      
        }
    } 
}
```

and commented out `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` but it is still redirecting to home. Even if I make `protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard'` it is routing same to `/home`. I don't know where problem exist.

I checked the `RedirectIfAunthenticated` middleware it has following code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Is there any problem due to this?

Please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `handle()` method in your `app\Http\Middlewares\RedirectIfAunthenticated.php` as follow. This middleware is intended to be changed by developers.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->is_admin == 0) {
            return redirect()->intended('/memberprofile');   
        } else {
            return redirect('/dashboard');      
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: @mustafa By changing `RedirectIfAunthenticated` you are changing the meaning of `guest` middleware. This may cause problems in long run for the application.

Answer (score 0):

In your `LoginController` define the following function :

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (Auth::user()->is_admin == 0)
    {     
        return redirect()->intended('/memberprofile');   
    }
    else 
    {
        return redirect('/dashboard');      
    } 
}
```

It will override the function `redirectPath` defined in the trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RedirectsUsers`.

Comment: It's still the same. :(

Comment: Can you show your `LoginController` in your question?

Comment: I hope your `/memberprofile` and `/dashboard` route are not under 'guest' middleware. If it is then please remove it because `guest` middleware can cause this problem.

Comment: I don't have any middleware in these routes, but anyways thanks for the help it worked by changing in `RedirectIfAunthenticated`.

Comment: Great if it worked but by changing `RedirectIfAunthenticated` you are changing the meaning of `guest` middleware. This may cause problems in long run for your application. You should check for where you are using `guest` middleware, maybe constructor of controllers.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#included-authenticating), when a user is successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to the `/home` URI. You can customize the post-authentication redirect location by defining a redirectTo property on the  `LoginController`, `RegisterController`, and `ResetPasswordController`:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/your_own_route';
```

Hope this Helps!